# How can I add Texture to a STL imported object?

Tags: textures, 3d-printing

I downloaded `STL` objects and want to add `Texture` to the surface. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide a sample object, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import the `"PolygonObjects"` and use `Texture`

```
polygons = Import["ExampleData/spikey.stl", "PolygonObjects"];
textures = ExampleData /@ ExampleData["ColorTexture"]; 

Graphics3D[{Texture[RandomChoice[textures]], 
Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, 1}}]} & @@@ polygons]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]